# How to get array values as return values from php REST api request?

Tags: php

This question has already being asked but I need a solution that is applicable to my problem. I was able to send values through my php REST api but only a single value was returned.

I want to be able to get all the array values from a curl request.

Below is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{

    $licence = $_POST['licence'];


        $ch = curl_init('http://totallightschools.com/apis/User/login.php?licence='.$licence);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data   = json_decode($response,true);
        if($data['status'] == true)
        {
        $_SESSION['licence'] = $data['licence'];
        echo $_SESSION['period'] = $data['period'];
        echo $_SESSION['user'] = $data['user'];
        echo $pin = $_SESSION['licence'];
            //echo "yes";
            //header("Location: setup.php?License=".$pin .'&period='.$_SESSION['period'].'&user='.$_SESSION['user']);
        }else
        {
            echo $data['message'];
        }


}
```

And for my api url

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    // get retrieved row
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // create array
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => true,
        "message" => "Successfully Validated!",
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "licence" => $row['licence'],
        "period" => $row['period'],
        "user" => $row['users']
    );
}
else{
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Invalid Licence Key Entered. Please contact the software company.",
    );
}
// make it json format
print_r(json_encode($user_arr));
```

Comment: And what's your question? As far as I see, the API you are calling does not take into account that there might be multiple results

Comment: What do you mean by _a single value_?  You mean a single row?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in your api code and need to return a multi dimensional array. Currently it will only return last value as you are overwriting `$user_arr`. Check below code:

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    // get retrieved row
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // create multidimensioanl array
    $user_arr[] = array(
        "status" => true,
        "message" => "Successfully Validated!",
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "licence" => $row['licence'],
        "period" => $row['period'],
        "user" => $row['users']
    );
}
else{
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Invalid Licence Key Entered. Please contact the software company.",
    );
}
// make it json format
print_r(json_encode($user_arr));
```

Hope it helps you.